# pm WARN npm You should probably upgrade to a newer version of node

Tags: node.js, npm

```
npm WARN npm npm does not support Node.js v14.17.3
npm WARN npm You should probably upgrade to a newer version of node as we
npm WARN npm can't make any promises that npm will work with this version.
npm WARN npm Supported releases of Node.js are the latest release of 4, 6, 7, 8.
npm WARN npm You can find the latest version at https://nodejs.org/
npm ERR! cb.apply is not a function
```

Im on windows and have tried upgrading node to version 16 and 18 and i still get this message when I try to npm install into  my project. Any help appreciated

.

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind I figured it out there were some npm files lurking around so i deleted them, removed node reinstalled node and it fixed it.